# Write a RSpec test for method that takes a single argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

I need to write the RSpec test case for a module that has a private method and takes a single Argument.

```
module x
  private
  def fun(para)
  end
end
```

I have a spec file where I tried to write a case like this. para and params are the arguments we can say.

```
RSpec.describe x do
  class spec
    include x
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end
  end

  describe "describe" do
    context "context" do
      it "should not truncate any normal text value" do
        obj = spec.new(params)
        # first 
        expect('dummy text').to obj.send(:fun).with(para)

        # second
        expect(obj).to receive(:fun).with(para);

        #third
        retr = obj.send(:fun).with(para);
        expect retr.to eq('dummy text')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

First, second and third, I used to get the output but these three ways didn’t work. They all are throwing some error.
Guys, can you help me to understant what I'm doing wrong? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please post what error you're getting?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale when i use this 
1. "obj = spec.new(params)
        # first 
        expect('dummy text').to obj.send(:fun).with(para)" getting error "ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)".
2.  "expect(obj).to receive(:conversation_text).with(para);" error "NoMethodError:
       undefined method `receive' for rspec"

Comment: 1. [Don't test private methods.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380287/why-is-unit-testing-private-methods-considered-as-bad-practice). Test the behavior of the class - not how it does its job. 2.  You're missing parens at `expect retr.to eq('dummy text')`. it should be `expect(retr).to eq('dummy text')`.3. `class spec` will raise an error since the identifier must be a constant in Ruby 3. I also wouldn't be suprised if RSpec reserves use of the name `spec`.

Comment: That last one also applies to `module x` If you're replacing the names for the sake of the example make sure the code still actually runs after your changes.

Comment: hi @max thanks for your reply. I used class name spec as an dummy. I have changed "expect retr.to eq('dummy text')" to as you told but still it giving me the error "ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

Comment: @max thanks for pointing out the point 1 but I want to write the test for private method.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where you got `obj.send(:fun).with(para);` from - maybe you're confusing [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send) with RSpec mocks.  `retr = obj.send(:fun, para)`?

Comment: @max forget about my method, can you give idea how you'll write the test case for this private method that takes single Argument that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: No I can't. There is nothing here that tells me what the actual behavior you're attempting to test is - you are just asking how to "test a private method that takes arguments" which in itself is a bad idea. I would just scrap this, take a 10 minute break and rethink this completely. Start by writing a spec that describes the behavior of classes that include the module instead.

Comment: @max thnaks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method is `private` you should not have to test it directly but in some cases, why not. 
I don't know what your `fun` method is supposed to do but here is some help.

```rb
RSpec.describe x do
  class MySpec
    include x
    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end
  end

  describe "#fun" do
    subject { my_spec.send(:fun).with(para) } 

    let(:my_spec) { MySpec.new(params) } 
    let(:params) { { foo: :bar } }
    let(:para) { 'dummy text' }

    it "should not truncate any normal text value" do
      expect(subject).to eq(para)
    end
  end
end
```